# Python dataframe join select where not exists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 dataframes below I would like to set the NxtCase value

```
dfObj = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'Case','NxtCase']) 
dfObj = dfObj.append({'ID': 11234, 'Case': 'A', 'NxtCase': ''}, ignore_index=True) 
dfObj = dfObj.append({'ID': 2347, 'Case': 'C', 'NxtCase': ''}, ignore_index=True) 
dfObj = dfObj.append({'ID': 31278, 'Case': 'E', 'NxtCase': ''}, ignore_index=True) 

dfObj2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'Case']) 
dfObj2 = dfObj2.append({'ID': 11234, 'Case': 'A' }, ignore_index=True) 
dfObj2 = dfObj2.append({'ID': 11234, 'Case': 'B'}, ignore_index=True) 
dfObj2 = dfObj2.append({'ID': 2347, 'Case': 'C'}, ignore_index=True) 
dfObj2 = dfObj2.append({'ID': 2347, 'Case': 'D'}, ignore_index=True) 
dfObj2 = dfObj2.append({'ID': 31278, 'Case': 'E'}, ignore_index=True) 
dfObj2 = dfObj2.append({'ID': 31278, 'Case': 'F'}, ignore_index=True)

print(dfObj)
print(dfObj2)
```

My objective is to compare dfObj to dfObj2 and set the NxtCase value.

The NxtCase value has to Equal the missing letter Case based on ID and not what currently exists in Case column.

For example ID =1 and Case= 'A' then the value NxtCase = 'B'
Any ideas on how I may set this value?

for instance here is sample
What I have

```
 ID Case NxtCase
 11234    A        
 2347     C        
 31278    E
```

This is my desired result

```
 ID Case NxtCase
 11234    A        B
 2347     C        D
 31278    E        F
```

I think this is easy I may just not be explaining it correctly. I am not that versed in python but I can do this is SQL. The final select table is what I am trying to accomplish in python

```
Create table #tmp1(
ID int,
[Case] varchar(20),
[NxtCase] varchar(20)
)

Create table #tmp2(
ID int,
[Case] varchar(20),
)



Insert into #tmp1(ID,[Case])
Select 23, 'A'
Union
Select 51, 'H'
Union
Select 63, 'L'


Insert into #tmp2(ID,[Case])
Select 23, 'A'
Union
Select 51, 'H'
Union
Select 63, 'L'
union
Select 23, 'D'
Union
Select 51, 'O'
Union
Select 63, 'E'



update t1
Set [NxtCase] =  t2.[Case]
from #tmp1 t1
    join #tmp2 t2
        on t1.ID = t2.ID
            and t1.[Case] <> t2.[Case] 

Select * from #tmp1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I completly got the difference between dfObj2 and dfObj;

However you might start work on your issue with the following method :

First we will need to get the index of the letter in the alphabet, for example for the letter `a` you may do the following:

```py
import string
indexOfA = string.ascii_uppercase.index('A')
```

Then you get the desired letter at the `index + 1` :

```py
letterB = string.ascii_uppercase[indexOfA + 1]
```

---

The complete example may be solved using by doing :

```py
import string

def findAndSet_nextLetter(x):
    return string.ascii_uppercase[
        string.ascii_uppercase.index(x.upper())+1
    ]

dfObj2['NxtCase']=dfObj2["Case"].apply(findAndSet_nextLetter)
```

Basically it apply the function findAndSet_nextLetter to the serie dfObj2["Case"]
resulting in :

```
    ID  Case    NxtCase
0   1   A   B
1   1   B   C
2   2   C   D
3   2   D   E
4   3   E   F
5   3   F   G
```

Comment: Thanks Odelin, I am looking for matching ID's ans returning the Letter that is missing. You cat really do the +1 because these number are in order and it may not be the case. the ID may be any nimber but they will be the same per each pair

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
dfObj['NxtCase'] = dfObj.apply(lambda row:dfObj2[dfObj2['ID'] == row['ID']][dfObj2['Case']!=row['Case']]['Case'], axis =1).fillna(method='bfill',axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

Complete question Solution posted here:
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29198267/Python-dataframe-join-select-where-not-exists.html#questionAdd